# How does Monte Carlo deal with unbounded functions with finite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, monte-carlo

Using Monte Carlo to evaluate the integral of a bounded function on a bounded interval is straightforward.

I have the following integral that I want to evaluate using Monte Carlo:

$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln (\sin(x)) dx$$
with $$f(x) = \ln (\sin(x))$$
It is worth noting that $$  \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = -\infty $$

What are the theoretical foundations that I need to take into consideration, and how to proceed with Monte Carlo in this case?

Comment: Why Monte Carlo? Why not Romberg or other numeric procedures? Just a suggestion,

Comment: Monte Carlo is what is demanded in the problem statement, so there should be a way to do it.

Comment: Simplest way, if using samples from a uniform distribution, is to reject any sample equaling zero, or within some tolerance of it.

Answer (score 0):

No matter if Monte Carlo or other numeric "approximators" to evaluate an integral with discontinuity at the borders, I'd suggest to use a non-uniform distribution of the samples to evaluate $f(x)$.

Two steps --
i) Change of limits:
let $\displaystyle x = \frac{b-a}{2}\cdot t + \frac{b+a}{2}$, then $\displaystyle dx = \frac{b-a}{2}dt$, and $\displaystyle I = \frac{b-a}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} f\left (\frac{b-a}{2}t+\frac{b+a}{2}\right ) dt$.
ii) Have non-uniform sample points:
let $t = 3/2\cdot u - 1/2\cdot u^3$, then $dt = \frac{3}{2}(1-u^2)du$, and

$\displaystyle I=\frac{3(b-a)}{4}\int_{-1}^{1} f\left (\frac{(b-a)}{4}u(3-u^2)+\frac{b+a}{2}\right )(1-u^2)du$

Now uniform distributed samples in $u$ over $[-1, 1]$ will get *closer* to the borders $a$ and $b$ in $x$ while $f(x)$ will not be sampled at $a$ or $b$ unless a rounding error slip due to used system/platform/calculator.

This idea is copied from [PPC ROM USR MNL](https://literature.hpcalc.org/items/1330), chapter "IG" (INTEGRATE), p. 220ff.

Comment: Result on two systems (virtual HP15C, emulated HP42S) is $-1,08879    $. on Reduce CAS: $-1.08892370862$ -- so it's highly likely the result is close to $-1$, but _no_ evidence or positive proof.